# Some icon font letters not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, icons, font-face, webfonts

We have built a custom icon set using Illustrator to draw the icons, copy/paste the shape to Glyphs, export to ttf, use font squirrel to create the various versions of the font.

All the icon work on all browsers except IE. In explorer 9 and down the "t" which is the twitter logo does not render.

I have re-exported the font several times with no luck. Has anyone ever heard of this. Could the vector drawing be wrong somehow?

Comment: Which font format are you using for IE? And What does it render, a rectangle or nothing? And you say "some" letters aren't working, so does that mean others are?

Comment: Css-> `code`@font-face {
    font-family: 'new_fontregular';
    src: url('intermountain-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('intermountain-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('intermountain-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('intermountain-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('intermountain-regular-webfont.svg#new_fontregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

Comment: Yes, all but 2-3 letters render the icon. The icons that do not render, render nothing.

Comment: from the dev tools in ie9 it looks like eot is the file type.

Comment: Solved - When copy/paste from Illustrator you must "group" the path even if the shape is one path or the icon will not render correctly in ie.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you, and good that you came back and posted the correct solution. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pasting a shape from Illustrator into Glyphs you must "group" the shape in Illustrator. Even if the shape is one path.